# Why am I seeing an unexpected value returned from toFixed()?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]So there is an input field where I enter my digits. And in one of the field is specified for decimal digits(after coma). So for example if I enter 2, the amount of after coma digits should be 2 in all fields. I used math round + toFixed function to do that but for some reason it doesnt give me the desired output, even thought a program reads decimal value
Please help me understand why!

```js
function convertToOthers(convertFrom, value, dec) {
  if (parseFloat(dec.value)) {
    switch (convertFrom) {
      case "mm":
        mmToOther(parseFloat(Math.round((value * 1000) / 10 / 100)).toFixed(parseFloat(dec.value)));
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="mm">Milimeters - mm</label>
<div>
  <input type="text" class="fname" id="mm" value="" name="inputNumber" oninput="convertToOthers('mm', this.value, dec)" /> <button class="buttonPic" onclick="copyFunction('mm')"></button><br><br>
</div>


<label for="dec">Decimal digits</label><br>
<div>
  <input type="text" class="fname decimal" id="dec" value=""><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: [`toPrecision`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision) is not what you need, use `toFixed` instead, but without `Math.round`.

Comment: Yes you right tehre should be toFixed, I just put a wrong method on description. Without Math.round it wasn´t working as well

Answer (score 0):

### toFixed()

I have used toFixed() to fix the number to decimal places.
The toFixed() method formats a number using fixed-point notation.

#### Syntax

*toFixed(digits)*

#### Return value

*A string representing the given number using fixed-point notation.*

#### Demostration:

```js
function mmToOther(x) {console.log("eval", x)}
function convertToOthers(convertFrom, value, dec){
    if(parseFloat(dec.value)){
        switch(convertFrom){
            case "mm"  : mmToOther(
                            Number.parseFloat(value).toFixed(parseFloat(dec.value))
                        );
                        break;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<label for="mm">Milimeters - mm</label>
    <div>
        <input 
            type="text"
            class="fname"
            id="mm"
            value=""
            name="inputNumber"
            oninput="convertToOthers('mm', this.value, dec)"
        > 
        <button class = "buttonPic" onclick = "copyFunction('mm')" >COPY</button>
        <br>
        <br>
    </div>


<label for="dec">Decimal digits</label><br>
    <div>
        <input type="text"  class="fname decimal" id="dec" value=""  ><br><br>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks but I just found an answer!